# SilverStripe File missing description

Tags: file, silverstripe

I am working on a download file list and I need a `Description` for a `File`.

I found the `File` class already has a `Content` `$db` property but there is no text field in the CMS to edit this property.

How can I set a `Content`/`Description` for a `File`?

Comment: In the code comments in framework/filesystem/file.php it mentions that the Content field is Typically unused, but handy for a textual representation of files, e.g. for fulltext indexing of PDF documents. You could create a DataExtension and implemet the updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) on that extension

Answer (score 2):

In SilverStripe 3.2 we can add a `Content` field to `File` by adding a `DataExtension`. `File` actually already contains a `Content` text variable but the field is not displayed by default.

To add the `Content` field to the `File` CMS fields we create a `FileExtension` `DataExtension`:

```
class FileExtension extends DataExtension {

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
        if (!$this->owner instanceof Folder) {
            $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TextareaField::create('Content'));
        }
    }
}
```

To add that extension to `File` we need to add the following code to our `config.yml`

```
File:
  extensions:
    - FileExtension
```